# Mapping custom strings found in JSON to POGO enum cases

Tags: json, groovy, enums, mapping, jsonslurper

In the context of a Grails application, we parse JSON into command objects. The automatic conversion from a JSON map to the POGO fails with an error like this:

> `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException`:
>   Cannot cast object '`{<snip>}`' with class '`groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`' to class '`SomeCmd`' due to:
>   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: No enum constant `Foo.my-bar`

I narrowed it down to this plain Groovy MWE:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

enum Foo {
    Bar("my-bar"),
    Ista("my-ista")

    final String s

    private Foo(String s) {
        this.s = s
    }
}

class SomeCmd {
    Foo foo
}

def some = new SomeCmd(new JsonSlurper().parseText('{ "foo" : "my-bar" }'))
println(some.foo)
```

This errors with

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: No enum constant `Foo.my-bar`

This is expected -- so far, so good.

Now, following [the documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.2/html/documentation/#_custom_type_coercion), I thought adding custom coercion from `String` to `Foo` might resolve the issue (also from [here](https://gist.github.com/EwanDawson/3864796)):

```
enum Foo {
    <snip>

    static Foo fromJsonString(String s) {
        return values().find { it.s == s }
    }
}

def oldAsType = String.metaClass.getMetaMethod("asType", [Class] as Class[])
String.metaClass.asType = { Class type ->
    type == Foo ?
            Foo.byJsonString(delegate as String) :
            oldAsType.invoke(delegate, [type] as Class[])
}
```

However, the error persists. Apparently, `JsonSlurper` does not use coercion at all, given that

```
println("my-bar" as Foo)
```

prints `Bar` as desired.

What is going on here? How can I get `JsonSlurper` to pick the correct enum cases by something *besides* the case name?

---

PS: Fun fact, if we change the second-to-last line to

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText('{ "foo" : "my-bar" }') as SomeCmd
```

the script prints `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy will happily use custom setters to construct the object. With `Foo.fromJsonString` as given in the question, define `SomeCmd` like so:

```
class SomeCmd {
    Foo foo

    void setFoo(Object jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject instanceof Foo) {
            this.foo = jsonObject
            return
        } else if (jsonObject instanceof String) {
            Foo f = Foo.fromJsonString(jsonObject)
            if ( null != f ) {
                this.foo = f
                return
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Foo for $jsonObject")
    }
}
```

Then, the code as given prints `Bar` as desired.

However, this doesn't help in Grails with parsing JSON into command objects -- Grails doesn't use coercion nor Groovy's map "magic". See [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52988656/539599).