# How does Grails 2.5.6 parse and map request JSON to POGO?

Tags: json, parsing, grails, pogo

*Tl;dr*: I want to get test `MyCmdTest."data bind works"` in [this code](https://github.com/reitzig/json-to-pogo-mwe/tree/b0044986c7330c8b149827b5fa8cf29d53d00202) green.
Thanks to Jeff Scott Brown for [getting me that far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992885/539599).

---

I have a POGO with some custom conversions from JSON which I expect to receive in a Grails controller:

```
def myAction(MyCmd myData) {
    ...
}
```

With:

```
@Validateable
class MyCmd {
    SomeType some

    void setSome(Object value) {
        this.some = customMap(value)
    }
}
```

Note how `customMap` creates an instance of `SomeType` from a JSON value (say, a String). Let's assume the default setter won't work; for instance, an pattern we have around more than once is an enum like this:

```
enum SomeType {
    Foo(17, "foos"),
    Bar(19, "barista")

    int id
    String jsonName

    SomeType(id, jsonName) {
        this.id = id
        this.jsonName = jsonName
    }
}
```

Here, `customMap` would take an integer or string, and return the matching case (or `null`, if none fits).

Now, I have a unit test of the following form:

```
class RegistrationCmdTest extends Specification {
    String validData // hard-coded, conforms to JSON schema

    void test() {
        MyCmd cmd = new MyCmd(JSON.parse(validData))
        // check members: success

        MyCmd cmd2 = JSON.parse(validData) as MyCmd
        // check members: success
    }
}
```

Apparently, `setSome` is called in both variants.

I also have a controller unit test that sets the request JSON to the same string:

```
void "register successfully"() {
    given:
    ResonseCmd = someMock()

    when:
    controller.request.method = 'POST'
    controller.request.contentType = "application/json"
    controller.request.json = validData
    controller.myAction()

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
    // successful validations: service called, etc.
}
```

Basically the same thing also runs as integration test.

However, the mapping *fails* when running the full application; `some == null`.

Which methods do I have to implement or override so Grails calls my conversions (here, `customMap`) instead of inserting `null` where it doesn't know what to do?

Comment: The link I provided above is for Grails 3.  In Grails 2.5.6 the exact same thing is happening to create the instance, but that happens at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.java#L472. (different class, same behavior for this)

Comment: FYI... You don't have to `controller.request.contentType = "application/json"` in your test because you are doing `controller.request.json = validData`, which will set the content type for you.  That happens at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.5.6/grails-test/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockHttpServletRequest.groovy#L108.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Unfortunately, `bindData` isn't really documented and it's hard to even write a unit test for it. It seems prudent to test against `DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance` instead, which is apparently the helper called.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm afraid I came across as overly snarky und unthankful. While I _am_ often frustrated with Grails, that shouldn't color my interactions here. So, sorry if I offended. I was and am truly thankful for the effort you put in trying to help me! (In the end, the issue was me not reading the correct piece of documentation, so I guess we talked past each other for a bit there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to customize data binding using the `@BindUsing` annotation:

```
@BindUsing({ newCmd, jsonMap ->
    customMap(jsonMap['someType'])
})
SomeType someType
```

See also [the MWE repo](https://github.com/reitzig/json-to-pogo-mwe/tree/non-trivial-bind).

Sources: [Hubert Klein Ikkink @ DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-custom-data), [Official Docs](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) (there are other ways to customize)